# Setting the display value of the selected option in HTML different to displayed option text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I have a select option, with the following example options.

```
(TYT) Toyota

(HD) Honda

(MT) Mitsubishi
```

I would like to only display the abbreviations on the select box after its' option is selected is possible without a javascript event listener to set value upon selection.

i.e `TYT` or `(TYT)` is also fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to do that, something like this:

```
    <select>
      <option value="0" data-abbr="None">Select</option>
      <option value="12" data-abbr="TTT">Toyota</option>
      <option value="13" data-abbr="HD">Honda</option>
      <option value="14" data-abbr="MT">Mitsubishi</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("select").change(function () {
        var option = $(this).find("option:selected");
        option.text(option.data("abbr"));
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Just use rails to feed in the necessary `data-abbr` attribute when generating your options.

*Edit* And here's a no JS version:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    option.TTT:after {
      content: " Toyota";
    }
    </style>
    <select>
      <option value="0" data-abbr="None">Select</option>
      <option value="12" class="TTT">TTT</option>
      <option value="13" data-abbr="HD">Honda</option>
      <option value="14" data-abbr="MT">Mitsubishi</option>
    </select>
```

That shows "TTT Toyota" when you look in the list but only the TTT value when you select it.  You'll need the `option.CLASS:after` selector for every option.

Comment: Yea mate thanks, I know thats possible but I was asking if it might be possible without the event listener.

Comment: Oh sorry, you could use CSS for to trick the names in but it's not pretty.  I'll update.